# Workflow email - Send to "Created by" - Without using Designer?

Tags: workflow, email

I'm using a 3-state workflow, and I want to send an email to the user who initiates the workflow, but I can't figure out how to do it. The server on which SP is installed does not have Designer enabled, so I have to do it through the web dialog. Is it possible?

On the second step, the email address to send to is hard coded, so that works every time. However, I cannot figure out how to send an email to the user who initiated the workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that entering [created by] instead of [Created by] worked... #SharePoint

Answer (score 0):

In a 3-state workflow, when modifying workflow properties, you can see the following options:

- define, what happens when workflow is triggered
- define, what happens when workflow is in the middle

On first stage, when workflow is triggered, you have the option to select who will be the person to receive and complete the task ('Creator' or 'Editor' of the item or custom selectable person) and also who will be notified about workflow start (it may be a different person, a boss e.g.)

Although you cannot prevent task from being sent, you can select to send notification email or not.
It is up to you to select person(s) (and add email address) to "To" field.

By default, if "Send email" checkbox is selected, the creator of the item will be notified.

- I suppose, in your case, workflow fires automatically when item is created, or manually after it.